# Referencing previously created files later in Python tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, error-000865

I'm converting a Python script that I usually run in the ArcMap Python window into a tool for others to use - something I always struggle with more than I should.

In the original scrip I have these lines:

```
streamOrder = arcpy.sa.StreamOrder(riverRastBin, Flow)
arcpy.sa.StreamToFeature(streamOrder, Flow, "RiverLines.shp")
riverDist = EucDistance("RiverLines", "", 25)
```

This worked fine in the original but when I run it in the tool it can't find RiverLines, presumably because it doesn't add it to the map of a layer, so I added a line to declare it:

```
streamOrder = arcpy.sa.StreamOrder(riverRastBin, Flow)
arcpy.sa.StreamToFeature(streamOrder, Flow, "RiverLines.shp")
RiverLines = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\RiverLives.shp"
riverDist = EucDistance("RiverLines", "", 25)
```

But no, this doesn't make any difference - same error message:

> ERROR 000865: Input raster of feature source data: RiverLines does not exist

Is there a special way I need to declare it as a shapefile, or can I take the output directly from the previous step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the immediate issue is that you have quoted `"RiverLines"` rather than a non-quoted variable `RiverLines`

```
RiverLines = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\RiverLives.shp"
riverDist = EucDistance(RiverLines, "", 25)
```

Instead of declaring `RiverLines = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\RiverLives.shp"` you could set the variable as the output of your `StreamToFeature`.  This doesn't work with every tool, so not 100% sure it will work.

```
RiverLines = arcpy.sa.StreamToFeature(streamOrder, Flow, "RiverLines.shp")
riverDist = EucDistance(RiverLines, "", 25)
```